# Default privileges for new users on public schema?

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I just created a database with an additional `application` schema.

And for our Java Spring Boot applications I created a new role with the following SQL scripts for setting up the privileges:

```
CREATE USER app_role WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '#########';

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA application TO app_role;
```

Now my expectation was that I could only create and delete tables within the schema `application` when logging in with this role.

However, I am also able to create and modify tables in the schema `public`.

Are there any default privileges for the `public` schema?

Why can I create tables in schemas I did not grant any privileges to?

Comment: [`alter default privileges ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `public` schema has a special role in PostgreSQL, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV) describes.

If you don't want that (and it can be a security problem), you can either `REVOKE` the `CREATE` privilege or even drop the schema alogether.